# Tune rule height in ruled float

Tags: floats, rules

I'm using `float` package to get floating environment with rules. I want to tune height of rules in `ruled` style for floatings of the package. Namely, I want bottom rule to be as thick as top one (like in `booktabs`'s tables).

I have already made some customization with low level TeX commands to have dot after float's number. But I can't get work similar trick for rule height.

My MWE is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{ruled}

\floatname{AlgoEnv}{Algorithm}
\newfloat{AlgoEnv}{htbp}{loa}[section]

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\floatc@ruled[2]{{\@fs@cfont #1.} #2\par}

% doesn't seem to work
\def\@fs@post{\hrule height.8pt depth0pt \kern2pt}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{First}

\begin{AlgoEnv}
\caption{blabla}
description
\end{AlgoEnv}

\end{document}
```

The result is as follows.

[image]

As you can see, bottom line is similar to the middle one and top rule is thicker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to patch the macro defining `\floatstyle{ruled}` before applying the style:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\fs@ruled}
 {\def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule\relax}}
 {\def\@fs@post{\kern2pt\hrule height 0pt depth .8pt\relax}}
 {}{}
\makeatother
\floatstyle{ruled}

\floatname{AlgoEnv}{Algorithm}
\newfloat{AlgoEnv}{htbp}{loa}[section]

\begin{document}
\section{First}

\begin{AlgoEnv}
\caption{blabla}
description
\end{AlgoEnv}

\end{document}
```

[image]